# How to reinstall mysql without damaging data?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

http://stuffthatspins.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-10-x-completely-remove-and-clean-mysql-installation/ shows how to reinstall everything.

I want to do something like this without reinstalling data.

Obviously I can't execute this:
delete preferences(the next find command will delete everything):

```
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

find all files with “mysql” on / and delete them:

```
find / -iname ‘mysql*’ -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Then I run

```
sudo aptitude purge mysql-server
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

But then I run into problem because I can't access some mysql-bin.0000x is not writeable or something.

If I keep mysql-bin.index empty or deleted it I got complaint that files are empty or inaccessible. I think the issue is that mysql doesn't have permission to access those file. However, I can't give them permission because the installation is supposedly automatic.

So what should I do?

This is for amazon-ec2

Comment: when you say I cant set the permissions, you used sudo chmod 777FILE-NAME ? btw 777 is kinda a security risk: http://tinyurl.com/cv6psay

Comment: Hnmmm... I'll try that.